# Reversing the order of words backwards in a string

Tags: c

Sorry for such a mediocre question, but I ran into what seems to be a tiny problem, but simply can't get over it. For my task I have to take a line of string from a file, and put it into another file backwards, for example:

```
one two three
four five six
```

would be

```
three two one
six five four
```

My problem is, is that I'm getting

```
 three two one
 si five four
```

So basically the flaw is that there is a space character at the beginning of each line and the last letter of the last word is always missing. Here's my reverse function:

```
void reverse(char input[], int length, char output[]) {
    char space = 32;
    input[length - 1] = space;
    int value = 0;
    int i, k = 0, j;
    for (i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
        if (input[i] == space) {
            for (j = i - 1; j >= k; j--, value++) {
                output[value] = input[j];
            }
            if (j == -1) {
                output[value] = space;
                value++;
            }
            k = i;
        }
    }

    char c = 0;
    for (int i = 0, j = length - 1; i <= j; i++, j--) {
        c = output[i];
        output[i] = output[j];
        output[j] = c;
    }
}
```

What I'm doing is first reversing each word by character, and then the whole line. If someone could help me find the last bits that I've missed I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Don't hard code character codes. `char space = 32;` should be `char space = ' ';`

Comment: The last letter is missing because you're writing a space on top of it. with "input[length-1] = space;" Why are you doing that? Do you need a space for some reason?

Comment: So much wrong with this code. It starts with the way you define the function itself. What is length? The size of the input including or excluding the terminating `\0` of the string? Will output have enough capacity to take the result? Or will this function become an accessory to murder... errm... mean memory corruption? Then, in the implementation you could follow a readable plan like: Turn input into words - push words on a stack, then pop from the stack and append to output. But yeah - its C - you don't even have access to a stack implementation. Use C++ ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flaws come from your approach:

- why do you force a space at offset `length - 1`? If you read the line with `fgets()`, there is probably a newline (`'\n'`) at the end of the line, but it might be missing at the end of the input, which would explain the `x` getting overwritten on the last line.
- you should not modify the input buffer.

Here is a simplified version, along with a simple `main` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(const char *input, int length, char *output) {
    int i, j, k, v;
    for (i = k = v = 0;; i++) {
        if (i == length || input[i] == ' ') {
            for (j = i; j-- > k; v++) {
                output[v] = input[j];
            }
            for (; i < length && input[i] == ' '; i++) {
                output[v++] = ' ';
            }
            if (i == length) {
                output[v] = '\0';
                break;
            }
            k = i;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0, j = length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        char c = output[i];
        output[i] = output[j];
        output[j] = c;
    }
}

int main() {
    char input[256];
    char output[256];

    while (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)) {
        reverse(input, strcspn(input, "\n"), output);
        puts(output);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
three two one
six five four
```

Here is a simpler reverse function that operates in one pass:

```
#include <string.h>

void reverse(const char *input, int length, char *output) {
    int i, j, k, v;
    for (i = k = 0, v = length;; i++) {
        if (i == length || input[i] == ' ') {
            for (j = i; j-- > k;) {
                output[--v] = input[j];
            for (; i < length && input[i] == ' '; i++) {
                output[--v] = ' ';
            }
            if (v == 0) {
                output[length] = '\0';
                break;
            }
            k = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. One thing that I want to add is that I wanted to use command line parameters for passing my files to the program, would that make any difference in a situation like this ?

Comment: @Nangs: how you get the filenames and/or the input or output streams is a separate issue from how you deal with a single line of text.

Answer (score 0):

Replace  `input[length - 1] = space;` with  `input[length] = space;`

Comment: That kinda solved the problem. Now I have the last letter for my "six", but the list is all messed up with "three" being in the first line, then " two one" in the second and "six five four" in the third one, as it should be.